# Why is my array empty?

Tags: php, arrays

Why is my `$dropdown` array empty?

I have not copied `$p` across

```
     foreach($p as $pat)
   {
    print'<pre>';
    print_r($pat['name']);
    print'</pre>';

   $c = Jojo::selectQuery("SELECT * FROM {cat} WHERE {parentid} =?", array($pat['categoryid']));

   foreach($c as $cat)
   {
        print'<pre>    ';
        print_r($cat['name']);
        print'</pre>';
   }

  $dropcat =  array();
  $dropcat[$cat[$pat['categoryid'][0]] = $pat['id']];

  print_r($dropcat);
}
```

Comment: @David This is my work account so I know the goings :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is a bracket issue?

```
$dropcat[$cat[$pat['categoryid'][0]] = $pat['id']];
// Should be
$dropcat[$cat[$pat['categoryid'][0]]] = $pat['id'];
```

But it's a littel hard to follow exactly without knowing the contents and $cat and $pat as I'm not sure those actually have the content in you expect - they wil have the LAST item from the foreach loop.

Comment: How can I make it to have all items?

Comment: In that case, I doubt $pat is a two dimentional array - $pat['category_id'][0]?!  Or do you mean $p[0]['category_id']?  $cat and $pat are the last rows in $p and $c - this _could_ be what you want (subject to  $pat being one dimetional, not two dimetional). Is this what you wanted? I can't see any logic in what you are trying to do. Use "echo" and print_r() to check what you have where. Then build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dropcat =  array();
print_r($dropcat);
```

These are both inside of your first `foreach` loop, causing it to be emptied each iteration of the loop. Remove the first line and put the second line after the curly brace, and try it again.

Comment: It's redeclaring the array, something you don't want in the middle of a `foreach` loop.